# Implementing SharedPreferences in a class to be able to get and save data from several fragments

Tags: java, android, persistence

I have an application with tabs and under one tab I have a `listfragment`, if I click on one listfragment I come to another listfragment and if I click an item there I come to a fragment that has textviews added programmatically.
If I click another tab I use the line:

```
container.removeAllViews();
```

To make the switching between tabs work correctly.

Now I would like to implement a `button` in the fragment that have `textviews`, I want a variable that I can +1 to if the button is pressed and i want to hold that in mind since I always want to show how many buttons been pressed in another tab. I also want to store that the button is pressed or not pressed.

What is the best way of doing this? and is it possible whem I'm using the line

`container.removeAllViews()` ?

So I have looked into `SharedPreferences`, many examples has the button inside the `activity` but I have `Buttons` inside of other `Fragments`. From these fragments I would like to save the state(save that it is pressed) for every `Button` and increase one variable when any `Button` is pressed.

When I run the application and press the button, I get an Error that is a NullPointerException and
the main thread is suspended and the debugger complains on the row:

```
preferences.savePrefs("BUTTON", true);
```

Anyone now why or how to fix this?

---

EDIT: If I don't have `SharedPrefererences` as a class for itself and insted put the three methods in the `Fragment` where the `Button` is, and change from `getApplicationContext()` to `getActivity()` it works. But since I want to be able to save from several `Fragments`, the best would be to have a class for this, right? I think that it might have something to do with how I get the context if `SharedPrefererences` is a class.

---

This is a `Fragment` with a `Button`:

```
package com.example.easysave;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlanFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

Button testedPlan;
SharedPreferences preferences;

boolean bpressed = false;
int value = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.planera_fragment, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.planera_ll);
    final LinearLayout horiz = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    horiz.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
    text.setText("Planera");

    Button testedPlan = new Button(getActivity());
    testedPlan.setText("Tried");
    testedPlan.setId(1);
    testedPlan.setOnClickListener(this);

    horiz.addView(text);
    horiz.addView(testedPlan);
    linearLayout.addView(horiz);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Button button = (Button)v;

    preferences.savePrefs("BUTTON", true);

    button.setPressed(true);
    value = value++;
    preferences.savePrefs("NUMBER", value);
    }
}
```

And this is the `SharedPreferences`

```
package com.example.easysave;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;


public class SharedPreferences extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadPrefs();
}

public void loadPrefs(){
    android.content.SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    boolean bpressed = sp.getBoolean("BUTTON", false);
    int value = sp.getInt("NUMBER", 0);
}

public void savePrefs(String key, boolean value){
    android.content.SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(key, value);
    edit.commit();
    System.out.println("Sparat!" +edit.commit());
}

public void savePrefs(String key, int value){
    android.content.SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putInt(key, value);
    edit.commit();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I think sharedPreferences can be useful http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: @Sweety is right, you need to store the variable in sharedPrefernces

here is example of how to use it http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html

Answer (score 1):

The best way to ratain any data/variable value for your app is to save it in sharedPreference.

refer to : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

for complete detail.

values stored in sharedPrefrence will retain untill user uninstall the app.

Comment: I have looked at this, and I have added some code and questions at the top.